# LXC container gets 2 IP addresses

Tags: ubuntu, lxc

I want to have a flat configuration where the host and guest all have their own static addresses on the network. For some unknown reason however, the container is assigned 2 addresses, 192.168.0.110 and 192.168.0.201. I'm only interested in having one, 192.168.0.201.

The host's network configuration:

```
# Host /etc/network/interfaces
auto lxcbr0
iface lxcbr0 inet static
    bridge_ports p4p1
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
    bridge_maxwait 0
    address 192.168.0.200
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.0.1
        dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
```

The guest's configuration inside the host:

```
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:08:b6:78
lxc.network.ipv4 = 192.168.0.201/24
```

The guest's network configuration:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

When I start the container and use `lxc-ls -f` I get:

```
NAME  STATE    IPV4                          IPV6                                    AUTOSTART  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
name  RUNNING  192.168.0.110, 192.168.0.201  2607:fa48:6de9:f3a0:216:3eff:fe08:b678  YES
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you explicitly asked for two IP addresses.

First, you asked the host to configure a static IP address for the container, which is active as the container starts. Then you asked *the container* to request a second IP address with DHCP.

You should remove those two lines from `/etc/network/interfaces` if you don't want the second IP address.

Comment: When I remove those lines and reboot, I can't connect to the internet anymore.

Comment: It was a resolv.conf issue, not an IP address issue. You were right.

Answer (score -3):

if you have a DHCP sever on that network, you will get two IP address, one from the lxc's dhcp server and the second one from your network DHCP

Comment: This is not true. If there are two (conflicting) DHCP servers in a segment, the faster one to answer will "win" the assignment of the address.